# unity wrong ragdoll behavior on slowmotion

Tags: unity, physics, ragdoll

I use simple logic to make a slow-motion effect. It works fine but it makes ragdoll animations feel like they have no weight and move easily.

This is the sample code:

```
    Time.timeScale += (1f / slowDownLength) * Time.unscaledDeltaTime;
    Time.timeScale = Mathf.Clamp(Time.timeScale, 0f, 1f);
```

I know it's based on fixedUpdate the physics engine used to run the physics simulation. If I want to do the time scaling manually with animation and speed, it can be a very hard process.